# Dockerfile setup for Deploying a Puppeteer Nodejs App on Droplet

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, puppeteer, digital-ocean

I have exhausted all the probable solutions on stackoverflow and beyond all to no success.

My use case is a very simple nodejs app that uses `puppeteer ^19.7.1`.

My directory structure has the file `.puppeteerrc.cjs` with content

```
const { join } = require('path');

/**
 * @type {import("puppeteer").Configuration}
 */
module.exports = {
    // Changes the cache location for Puppeteer.
    cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, '.cache', 'puppeteer'),
};
```

However, when the server starts I am constantly greeted with the error message:

```
/workspace/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-1069273/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Everything works well on my localhost. The issue only starts when I hosted it on Digital Ocean Droplets.

I tried copying over the Dockerfile setup here https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting#running-puppeteer-in-the-cloud as is over to the root of my project to see if the issue will be resolved all to no available.

So, please I would really appreciate if any one can help me with a working Dockerfile configuration to address this as I've spent all day on this to no success.

I intend to host the app on Digital Ocean's *Droplets*

Thanks in anticipation for your time